# How to sort and display by title in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been try examples the past couple of days with no luck. 
I have a table named Article with columns such as bullet, powder, and calibertitle.  I set up a form in which I can enter in particular details such as bullet brand, powder brand, caliber name, etc.

I am using SQLite.

How can I search for a particular word in a title and only display the title and corresponding info if the title has that word?

I can list all data but I am not sure how to sort through it.  I would also like to do something like listing data in alphabetical order.

Also, if I created another controller, is it possible for me to list/display the same columns under the new controller?

/views/articles/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Load Data</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bullet</th>
    <th>Powder</th>
    <th>Caliber</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= article.bullet %></td>
     <td><%= article.powder %></td>
     <td><%= article.calibertitle %></td>
     <td><%= link_to '[View]', article_path(article) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to '[Edit]', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to '[Delete]', article_path(article),
             method: :delete,
             data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', controller: 'welcome' %>
<p>
</table>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```

/models/article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  validates :calibertitle, presence: true,
                           length: { minimum: 3 }

end
```

Comment: "I have been try examples the past couple of days with no luck." What have you tried? [`#where`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) and [`#order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) are well Documented

Comment: I am not sure about the first part of your question, but to store items by alphabet you could simply pass  `@articles = Article.order(:title)` to your index action

Answer (score 1):

In your controller assuming you have a column named `calibertitle`:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all.order(:calibertitle)
end
```

To get a Articles with a specific value in a field: `Article.where(calibertitle: '308')`

You can try this in rails console just to verify. You can also do `.reverse_order(:field)`  if you need it sorted in... reverse.

Comment: I do have a column named calibertitle.

Comment: Does this work? You also don't really need the .all you can just do Article.order(:calibertitle)

Comment: I do have a column named calibertitle.  Article.all.order(:calibertitle) does work but the Article.where(calibertitle: '308') does not work when I enter in strings that I know are in my calibertitle colum.  "308" for example.

Comment: Article.where(calibertitle: '308') doesn't even work in rails console?

Comment: Article.where(calibertitle: 308 gives me this in console: Article Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`powder` = '308'

Comment: Can you add your db migration for Articles? Not sure why calling calibertitle: would search against the powder: field